# Find the range of $(1/2)T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V=M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space consisting of all $2 \times 2$ real matrices. Define a transformation $T : V → V$ by

$$             
                 T(A)=AP-PA, \mbox{ where } 
P = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The transformation $T^2: V → V$ is defined to be $T^2(A) = T(T(A))$, for each $A ∈ V$. Given $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$, the transformation $cT$ is defined to be $(cT)(A) = cT(A)$, for each $A ∈ V$.

Find the Range of $(1/2)T^2$.

This is a question my professor gave me for practice. There were some other questions about proving that $T$ is linear and stuff like that but I have no idea where to even begin with this.

(ps. I apologize if my formatting is not proper but this is the first time I have asked a question on this website).

Comment: A linear operator is determined by it values on a basis. A tour de force approach is to evaluate $(1/2)T^2$ on a basis and then extract a maximal linearly independent set from their images. Another way is to compute $T^2(A)= (AP-PA)P-P(AP-PA)=AP^2-PAP - PAP + P^2A$ Since $P^2=I$ then $T^2(A)=2PAP$. Therefore $(1/2)T^2(A)=PAP$. Observe that then $(1/2)T^2$ is the composition of left multiplication by $P$ and right multiplication by $P$. Since $P$ is invertible so are the sided multiplications. Therefore $(1/2)T^2$ is an isomorphism. The range is the whole space.

Comment: @Bettybel Sorry I don't quite understand your explanation. I get it up until the P^2 =I part but then you lose me at that point

Comment: Bettybel's comment has a mistake, perhaps that is why it is hard to understand.

Comment: All: I deleted a subchain of comments as it got a bit too personal. Flags were also flying. There was also some collateral damage.

Comment: Bettybel's comment starts out fine, but then there are a few sign errors. I don't see a very clean way of doing this. We do see that $I$ and $P$ are both in $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$, and hence also in the kernel of $\dfrac12T^2$, but that doesn't really say very much about the range (other than that it is at most 2-dimensional). I would bail out and just do it the way in Zach Teitler's (+1) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. Then
$$
  T(A) = AP - PA = \begin{pmatrix} b & a \\ d & c \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ a & b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b-c & a-d \\ d-a & c-b \end{pmatrix} .
$$
Continuing,
$$
  T^2(A) = T(T(A)) = \begin{pmatrix} (a-d)-(d-a) & (b-c)-(c-b) \\ (c-b)-(b-c) & (d-a)-(a-d) \end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} a-d & b-c \\ c-b & d-a \end{pmatrix} .
$$
So
$$
  \frac{1}{2} T^2(A) = \begin{pmatrix} a-d & b-c \\ c-b & d-a \end{pmatrix} .
$$

Before going on, I'd like to point out a slightly different approach suggested in the comments. Note that $P^2 = I$. Then
$$
  T^2(A) = T(A)P - PT(A) = (AP-PA)P - P(AP-PA) = AP^2 - PAP - PAP + P^2A = 2(A-PAP),
$$
so $\frac{1}{2} T^2(A) = A-PAP$ (**not** $\frac{1}{2}T^2(A)=PAP$). One can compute
$$
  A - PAP = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} d & c \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}
$$
and get the same expression as before.

Now, having an expression for $\frac{1}{2} T^2$ is nice, but the question was to describe the range of this operator. What kind of description would you like? If you want equations for the range, some obvious ones pop out: set
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} a-d & b-c \\ c-b & d-a \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{pmatrix},
$$
then it's clear that $x+w = 0$ and $y+z = 0$. It's clear that these equations are independent. You already know that $\frac{1}{2} T^2$ is linear (right?) so its range is a linear subspace in $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, which is $4$-dimensional. Since we've written $2$ independent equations, we know the range has dimension at most $2$. A priori, however, there could be additional equations.

To see that there are no other equations we could, for instance, write down $2$ independent elements of the range, such as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ (can you see which matrices $A$ give these as $\frac{1}{2}T^2(A)$?).

So the range is at most $2$-dimensional (because we have $2$ equations and a $4$-dimensional ambient space) and it is also at least $2$-dimensional (because we have these $2$ independent elements). We can conclude that the range is precisely $2$-dimensional, spanned by the two elements given above. And that gives you a second description of the range, if you need a basis for it rather than equations.

For example, having this basis makes it very easy to check that $\frac{1}{2} T^2$ is a projection onto its range.

Comment: This is very helpful but I'm not quite sure how you got the equations x+w =0 and y+z = 0

Comment: If $x=a-d$ and $w=d-a$, then $w=-x$, $x+w=0$. I'm using $x,y,z,w$ as the coordinates in $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$.